# Neo4j: Rewriting UNION returns more then it should

Tags: mysql, neo4j, cypher, union

I'm migrating a MySQL database to a Neo4j one, but I can't rewrite this query correctly.

MySQL Query:

```
SELECT ID, Nome, Fotografia
    FROM Participante AS pa
    INNER JOIN Filme_temAtor_Participante AS fa ON fa.Participante_ID = pa.ID
    WHERE fa.Filme_ID = 1
UNION
SELECT ID, Nome, Fotografia
    FROM Participante AS pr
    INNER JOIN Filme_temRealizador_Participante AS fr ON fr.Participante_ID = pr.ID
    WHERE fr.Filme_ID = 1
ORDER BY Nome ASC;
```

From SQL to Neo4j I stopped using ids and started using the name itself. I made 2 cypher queries, the first one works fine, but the second one doesn't:

First one:

```
MATCH(f:Filme {Titulo: "Justice League"})
MATCH(a:Participante)<-[:TEM_ATOR]-(f)
MATCH(b:Participante)<-[:TEM_REALIZADOR]-(f)
RETURN a,b;
```

Second one:

```
MATCH(f:Filme {Titulo: "Justice League"})
MATCH(a:Participante)<-[:TEM_ATOR]-(f)
WITH COLLECT({Nome:a.Nome,Fotografia:a.Fotografia}) AS atores
MATCH(b:Participante)<-[:TEM_REALIZADOR]-(f)
WITH atores + COLLECT({Nome:b.Nome,Fotografia:b.Fotografia}) AS ps
UNWIND ps AS p
RETURN  p.Nome, p.Fotografia;
```

The output looks like this:
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qdddY.png)

Since the project is in Portuguese I'll provide a dictionary of the relevant words:

- Participante -> Participant
- Filme -> Movie
- Fotografia -> Photo
- temAtor -> hasActor
- temRealizador -> hasDirector
- Nome -> Name

Any help would be greatly apreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass along `f` in the `WITH` clause:

```
MATCH(f:Filme {Titulo: "Justice League"})
MATCH(a:Participante)<-[:TEM_ATOR]-(f)
WITH f, COLLECT({Nome:a.Nome,Fotografia:a.Fotografia}) AS atores
MATCH(b:Participante)<-[:TEM_REALIZADOR]-(f)
WITH atores + COLLECT({Nome:b.Nome,Fotografia:b.Fotografia}) AS ps
UNWIND ps AS p
RETURN  p.Nome, p.Fotografia;
```

If you do not pass it along, `f` will be treated as a new variable and it can be bound to any node, not just the *Justice League* movie.

Comment: Why don't I have to pass `f` on the second one? This is confusing I probably don't understand the `WITH` keyword fully.

Comment: You don't have to pass it along as you are no longer using it in the last clauses (`UNWIND` and `RETURN`).